# How can I return the content of an XML field as a recordset?

Tags: sql, xml

Say I've got this table (SQL Server 2005):

```
Id => integer  
MyField => XML
```

**Id  MyField**

```
1   < Object>< Type>AAA< /Type>< Value>10< /Value>< /Object>< Object>< Type>BBB< /Type><Value>20< /Value>< /Object>  
2   < Object>< Type>AAA< /Type>< Value>15< /Value>< /Object>  
3   < Object>< Type>AAA< /Type>< Value>20< /Value>< /Object>< Object>< Type>BBB< /Type>< Value>30< /Value>< /Object>
```

I need a TSQL query which would return something like this:

```
Id  AAA     BBB  
1   10      20  
2   15      NULL  
3   20      30
```

Note that I won't know if advance how many `'Type'` (eg AAA, BBB, CCC,DDD, etc.) there will be in the xml string.

Comment: Note that  I won't know if advance how many 'Type' (eg AAA, BBB, CCC,DDD, etc.) there will be in the xml string.

Comment: you will have to use dynamic sql and cursors then most likely. no single statement to get what you want i don't think.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [XML querying in sql server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122.aspx#sql2k5_xqueryintro_topic8) to do that.

somethings like

```
select id, MyField.query('/Object/Type[.="AAA"]/Value') as AAA, MyField.query('/Object/Type[.="BBB"]/Value) AS BBB
```

not sure if that's 100% correct xquery syntax, but it's going to be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use the [XMLDataDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.aspx).  Using this class you can retrieve the data as XML load it into the XmlDataDocument and then use the Dataset property to access it as if it were a standard dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `CROSS APPLY`. Here's an example based on your request:

```
declare @y table (rowid int, xmlblock xml)
insert into @y values(1,'<Object><Type>AAA</Type><Value>10</Value></Object><Object><Type>BBB</Type><Value>20</Value></Object>')
insert into @y values(2,'<Object><Type>AAA</Type><Value>15</Value></Object>')
insert into @y values(3,'<Object><Type>AAA</Type><Value>20</Value></Object><Object><Type>BBB</Type><Value>30</Value></Object>')

select y.rowid, t.b.value('Type[1]', 'nvarchar(5)'), t.b.value('Value[1]', 'int')
from @y y  CROSS APPLY  XmlBlock.nodes('//Object') t(b)
```

Oh, and your example XML is invalid, the first row is missing the opening `Value` element for `Type BBB`.